# Simultaneously iterate over multiple list and capture difference in values

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

Consider API returning four lists as output. Let's consider output as

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2,3,4]
c = [1,2,4,3]
d = [1,2,3,5]
```

Now, first we want to compare these lists are equal or not.

Lists are equal only if elements and there indexes matches.
For example, from above lists, `a` and `b` are equal. But `a` and `c` are not equal.

If the lists are not equal, then output is expected as: *this element at this index in this list is not same as other*.

***For comparing and getting differences of two lists, I have written below code.***

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] != c[i]:
        print "Expected value at ",i," is ",a[i]
        print "But got value ",c[i],"in second list"
```

***Now question is how to achieve this for all four above lists?***

Comment: What would you expect to happen if all four lists are completely different?

Comment: It should be give that all lists are all different and print that lists.

Comment: Can't you just use 4C2 loops ? Mention if there are any constraints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over each list simultaneously and compare the value at each index. In the below example, I am comparing the value of list `a` with remaining lists.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2,3,4]
c = [1,2,4,3]
d = [1,2,3,5]

for i, x in enumerate(zip(a, b, c, d)):
    print('--------- Index: {}'.format(i))
    base = x[0]
    for j, y in enumerate(x[1:], 2):
        if base!=y:
            print('{} not equal to {} : --> List {}'.format(base, y, j))
```

which prints:

```
--------- Index: 0
--------- Index: 1
--------- Index: 2
3 not equal to 4 : --> List 3
--------- Index: 3
4 not equal to 3 : --> List 3
4 not equal to 5 : --> List 4
```

Comment: How to find in which list we have different value?

Comment: Use enumerate over inner `for` loop as well to know the index. Check edit

Comment: Great. True confession > Took me while to understand your code. Loved it how you used enumerate along with zip.

Answer (score 1):

From the comment:

> How to find in which list we have different value?

```
import collections as ct

counter = ct.Counter(map(tuple, [a,b,c,d]))                # make hashable keys w/tuples
base = counter.most_common(1)[0][0]                        # find most frequent sequence
[list(seq) for seq in counter if seq != base]              # filter uncommon sequences
```

Output (the non-matching lists):

```
[[1, 2, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 5]]
```

We collect all similar [sequences](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/typesseq.html) as keys in a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#counter-objects).  If all sequences match, there should only be one entry in the `Counter` dictionary.  Otherwise, filter the remaining sequences.

Comment: How to find in which list we have different value?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a list `mylist = [a, b, c,d]` Then loop through checking which ones are equal and which ones are not equal.

```
for i in range(len(mylist)-1)
   for j in range(i+1, len(mylist))
       # Check mylist[i] agaist mylist[j] and report results
```

For example, this will test a against b, c, and d
b against c and d
c against d