# Create New List of Repeated Elements Within a Given List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want my program to take a list that is already created, go through it and check for any elements that repeat. Then create a new list with just the elements that repeat.

```
def repeated_elements(data):
    repeats = []
    for element in data:
        result = data.count(element)
        if result > 1:
            repeats.append(element)
       return data
print (repeated_elements([1, 2, 3, 1, 3]))#should print out [1, 3, 1, 3]
print (repeated_elements([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))# should print out []
print (repeated_elements([5, 5, 5, 5, 5]))# should print out [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
print (repeated_elements([10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8]))# should print out [10, 9, 10, 10, 9]
```

The program ends up printing out the starting sets

Comment: You're method's retuning the same data you're passing into it with no modifications, perhaps you mean to return the `repeats` instead of the `data`.

Comment: Similar to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705305/simultaneously-iterate-over-multiple-list-and-capture-difference-in-values/41705703#41705703

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are returning data instead of repeats so it ends up printing out the starting set. 
Second - your indentation of the return statement inside the for loop will return the result in the first iteration of the loop. If you fix that, the code will work.

```
def repeated_elements(data):
    repeats = []
    for element in data:
        result = data.count(element)
        if result > 1:
            repeats.append(element)
    return repeats
```

Answer (score 3):

Better way to achieve this via using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with *list comprehension* expression as:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3]

>>> my_counter = Counter(my_list)
>>> [i for i in my_list if my_counter[i]>1]
[1, 3, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3]
>>> repeated = [i for i in lst if lst.count(i) > 1]
[1, 3, 1, 3]
```